# How can I display image from my MySQL database to pdf using Dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

After I attempt to display an image from the database in a PDF using DomPDF, it doesn't appear, and the loading speed is slow.

**My view:**

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="{{ $logo }}" alt="Sample Image" style="height: 50px;">
</div>
```

I'm working on a Laravel project and using DomPDF to generate PDF certificates. The code below is from my `CertificateController`, which handles the generation of these certificates:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Certificate;
use App\Models\Term;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
use Auth; // Import the Auth facade
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF as DomPDFPDF;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth as FacadesAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class CertificateController extends Controller
{
    public function generateCertificate($termId)
    {
        // Fetch the term and relevant data
        $term = Term::find($termId);

        // Check if the term and necessary data are available

        // Get the authenticated user's name
        $userName = FacadesAuth::user()->name;
        $userLastName = FacadesAuth::user()->last_name;

        // Fetch the certificate data, including the logo URL
        $certificate = Certificate::first();

        // Prepare data for the certificate template
        $data = [
            'username' => $userName, // Use the authenticated user's name
            'userlastname' => $userLastName,
            'course' => $term->course->title, // Assuming that 'course' is a property of the Term model
            'term' => $term->title, // Assuming that 'title' is a property of the Term model
            'date' => $term->finish_date, // Assuming that 'title' is a property of the Term model
            'logo' => asset('storage/' . $certificate->logo),
            'position_1' => $certificate->position_1, 
            'position_2' => $certificate->position_2, 
            'name_1' => $certificate->name_1, 
            'name_2' => $certificate->name_2, 
        ];
        // Load the certificate template HTML
        $html = view('certificate.certificate', $data)->render();

        // Generate the PDF from the HTML
        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);

        // Set the paper size to certificate size (e.g., A4) and landscape orientation
        $pdf->setPaper('Letter', 'landscape');;

        // Set the file name for the PDF
        $fileName = 'certificate_' . $term->id . '.pdf';

        // Optionally, you can store the PDF on the server or force download
        // Example: $pdf->save(storage_path('certificates/' . $fileName));
        // Example: return $pdf->download($fileName);

        // Display the PDF in the browser
        return $pdf->stream($fileName);
    }

    // Method to handle the form submission
    public function index()
    {
        $certificate = Certificate::first(); // Retrieve a single certificate
        return view('contents.admin.badges.index', compact('certificate'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start by checking the URL of the image in the HTML of your view. Do you see the image there, and is it a full URL, including protocol and domain? Then make sure the `isRemoteEnabled` option is enabled. However, I often find it is easier to work with base64 encoded images when using DomPDF, so it doesn't need to retrieve external content at all.